# Can't pass correctly the parameters of batch script into a command inside a loop statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I have a problem with passing parameters to commands inside the script which downloads online stream to individual directory and then fixes errors using ffmpeg.

First I check if directory exists and if not then create one:

```
if exist %1 (
      echo Directory exists
   ) ELSE (
      mkdir "%1%"
      echo Directory created
   )
```

And then there is a main loop which tries to download the stream and fix errors in it.

```
for /L %%C in (1,1,10000) do (

      streamlink -o "%%1\%%1%%C.mp4" "some.url/%2" best   
      if exist %1\%1%C.mp4 (
          d:\streamlink\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -loglevel debug -i "%1\%1%C.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy "%1\%1%C_o.mp4" 1>"%1%\log\%1%%C.log" 2>"%1%\err\%1%%C.err"
         )
      timeout /T 300 
    )
```

So for example if I execute:

```
script.cmd foo xyz
```

then in first loop should be executed:

```
streamlink -o "foo\foo1.mp4" "some.url/xyz" best   
      if exist foo\foo1.mp4 (
          d:\streamlink\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -loglevel debug -i "foo\foo1.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy "foo\foo1_o.mp4" 1>"foo\log\foo1.log" 2>"foo\err\foo1.err"
         )
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Is your **`[%]`** key sticking on your keyboard? or is there some automation software sporadically adding those characters?

Comment: No, I tried almost any known to me way with those [%] characters to make script working as I want and here I pasted my last try figuring it out which still don't work

Comment: How in the world did you manage to type `%1\%%C` three different ways? `%1\%%C` is the only correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `call /?` and read the output help explaining how arguments of a batch file can be referenced from within a batch file. Argument 0 is the batch file currently processed by `cmd.exe`.

I suggest this batch file for the task although not knowing what the **FOR** loop really does.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1" == "" (
    echo ERROR: %~nx0 must be called with a directory path as first argument.
    goto EndBatch
)

if "%~2" == "" (
    echo ERROR: %~nx0 must be called with ??? as second argument.
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Assign the directory path to an environment variable.
set "DirectoryPath=%~1"
rem Make sure the directory path contains \ and not / as directory separator.
set "DirectoryPath=%DirectoryPath:/=\%"
rem Make sure the directory path ends with a backslash.
if not "%DirectoryPath:~-1%" == "\" set "DirectoryPath=%DirectoryPath%\"

rem Check if the directory exists already and create it otherwise.
if exist "%DirectoryPath%" (
      echo Directory exists.
) else (
    md "%DirectoryPath%"
    if exist "%DirectoryPath%" (
        echo Directory created.
    ) else (
        echo ERROR: %~nx0 failed to create directory "%DirectoryPath:~0,-1%"
        goto EndBatch
    )
)

rem Get name of last directory from directory path for the various file names.
for %%I in ("%DirectoryPath:~0,-1%") do (
    set "VideoFileName=%DirectoryPath%%%~nxI"
    set "StdLogFileName=%DirectoryPath%log\%%~nxI
    set "ErrLogFileName=%DirectoryPath%err\%%~nxI
)

rem Create the two additional subdirectories with suppressing the
rem error messages output on these directories existing already.
md "%DirectoryPath%log" 2>nul
md "%DirectoryPath%err" 2>nul

for /L %%I in (1,1,10000) do (
    streamlink.exe -o "%VideoFileName%%%I.mp4" "some.url/%~2" best
    if not errorlevel 1 if exist "%VideoFileName%%%I.mp4" (
        "D:\streamlink\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel debug -i "%VideoFileName%%%I.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy "%VideoFileName%%%I_o.mp4" >"%StdLogFileName%%%I.log" 2>"%ErrLogFileName%%%I.log"
    )
    rem Don't know what this wait is for.
    %SystemRoot%\Sytem32\timeout.exe /T 300
)

rem Remove all empty standard log files.
for %%I in ("%StdLogFileName%*.log") do if %%~zI == 0 del "%%I"
rem Remove the standard log file directory on being empty now.
rd "%DirectoryPath%log" 2>nul

rem Remove all empty error log files.
for %%I in ("%ErrLogFileName%*.log") do if %%~zI == 0 del "%%I"
rem Remove the error log file directory on being empty now.
rd "%DirectoryPath%err" 2>nul

:EndBatch
echo(
endlocal
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `timeout /?`

See also:

- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)